# How can I get rid of some "|" vertical lines in a table?

Tags: tables

I want to create a table like this

[image]

But mine is

[image]

Here's how I make it:

```
\begin{tabular}{|c|l|l|l|l|l|}
\hline
\textit{Text} & ``Tom & Spink & has & a & harpoon.''\\
\hline
\hline
\textit{Transcription 1} & L+H* & L+H* & & & \! H* \\ & & & & & L-L\% \\
\hline
\textit{Transcription 2} & L* & L* & & & L*\\
 & H- & L- & & & L-L\%\\
 \hline

\end{tabular}
```

Pls help.

Comment: The `|` in `\begin{tabular}` tell TeX where you want the vertical lines.  Each letter states which way the column should be aligned.

Comment: The other way to remove vertical lines is to use \multicolumn.

Answer (score 3):

You only need to omit `|` in column specification between columns, where you not like to have vertical lines:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{array} 

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|>{\itshape}c | l l l l l|}  % <---
    \hline
Text            & ``Tom & Spink & has   & a & harpoon.''\\
    \hline
    \hline
Transcription 1 & L+H*  & L+H*  &       &   & !H*       \\ 
                &       &       &       &   & L-L\%     \\
    \hline
Transcription 2 & L*    & L*    &       &   & L*        \\
                & H-    & L-    &       &   & L-L\%     \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]